# Не работают аннотации @BeforeAll,@BeforeEach

Tags: java, junit, тестирование, аннотации

Всем привет, только начинаю изучать Junit и вот столкнулся с проблемой. Написал простой тест:

```
public class MainTests {

private List<Employee> employeeList;

@BeforeAll
public void sayHello(){
    System.out.println("hello");
}

@BeforeEach
public void listInit() {
    employeeList = new ArrayList<>();
    employeeList.add(new Employee(1, "John", "Smith", "USA", 25));
    employeeList.add(new Employee(2, "Ivan", "Petrov", "RU", 23));
}

@Test
public void parseCsv() {
    String fileName = "data.csv";
    String[] columnMapping = new String[]{"id", "firstName", "lastName", "country", "age"};
    List<Employee> list = Main.parseCSV(columnMapping, fileName);

    Assert.assertEquals(employeeList, list);

}
```

Насколько я понимаю, у меня метод помеченный аннотацией BeforeAll должен отработать один раз перед началом всех тестов(чего не происходит вообще). Также метод с аннотацией BeforeEach должен отработать перед каждым тестом (чего тоже вообще не происходит)
Не подскажите, почему не отрабатывают данные аннотации?
мой pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.guluev</groupId>
    <artifactId>CsvJsonParser</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>5.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: из какого пакета импортируется `@Test`? как запускаете? Я не вижу определения плагинов `maven-surefire-plugin` и `maven-failsafe-plugin` как описано в https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-build-maven

Comment: 1)добавил указанные плагины: maven-surefire-plugin и maven-failsafe-plugin все равно не работает 2)@Test импортируется из пакета (import org.junit.Test) 3)запускаю вручную через idea (пробовал и через терминал mvn test, в таком случае тесты вообще не запускаются, пишет Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы импортируете неправильную аннотацию из junit 4.

Вам нужна аннотация `org.junit.jupiter.api.Test` из junit 5.

`BeforeAll` и `BeforeEach` это из junit 5. Из IDEA вы запускаете их с junit 4, который о них ничего не знает и никак их не обрабатывает. При запуске в maven он правильно пробует запускать тесты junit 5, но у вас ни одного такого теста нет - потому он их и не находит.